# You can either go by bus or by taxi. OR You can go either by bus or by taxi

Tags: parallelism

> You can either go by bus or by taxi.

> You can go either by bus or by taxi.

I think the first is wrong and the second is right, for there is parallel struction.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that example 1 does not comply with parallelism.  For clarity, I have bracketed the phrases separated by *or* of the correlatve conjunction pair.

> You can either [go by bus] or [by taxi].

> You can go either [by bus] or [by taxi].